# C# iTextSharp: How to specify Spot Colors

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp to add text to PDF files.

The Text Color is usually specified as CMYK, but will require the need to specify spot/special colors.

[There is an example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/PDF-RTF/SpotColorsforText.htm)

In the Line:

```
PdfSpotColor spotColour = new PdfSpotColor("PANTONE 100 CV", 0.5f, new GrayColor(0.9f));
```

Does anyone know the description and meaning of the paramaters

so we have (string name, float tint, Color altcs)

I assume the name is the Color Separation Name. Not 100% sure what tint is or its range, is that some kind of alpha/transaparency value? and is the altcs a display color, rather than the separation layer used for actual printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pulled up somiTextSharp code I had and my method parameters are different for the `PdfSpotColor`.  I only have 2 parameters, and there are no overloads.  The example you gave is from the original java project.  I think that is why they are different.

Here is what I have:

```
var color = new PdfSpotColor("spotColorName", new BaseColor(50, 50, 50));
```

... where the numbers are the red, green blue.  The BaseColor constructor has overloads, so you can even give it a .NET `Color` if you want.

Unfortunately, I don't know much else about this class.  Hope that helps!